# MySQL SELECT two field then set second's value field INTO first variable

Tags: mysql

As normal you can use `SELECT "1", "2" INTO @a, @b`.
What I wanna do is set the second's value field into a single variable.

- Current: `SELECT "1", "2" INTO @b` result is @b equal "1"
- Expectation: `SELECT "1", "2" INTO @b` result is @b equal "2"

Does Mysql have anything to achieve that?

Comment: It does, although INTO is a reserved word for usage in procedures/functions only (or to export data). Maybe you are trying to use variables instead? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-variables/

Comment: you can use mysql stored procedure for this.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes correct variables is solving my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next approach:

```
SELECT "1", @b:="2";

SELECT @b;
```

[Try this SQL here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4d7e25b763fb289c64f3aca10614e4d4&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)